# How to make Regex case sensitive

Tags: regex, powershell

In most other languages I have used, regex has alway been case sensitive, however powershell seems to be unorthodox and regex is case insensitive. How do I change this?

```
"a" -match "A"
```

Expected output:

```
False
```

Actual output:

```
True
```

How can I change this?

Comment: Use `-cmatch`, if you put `-c` in front of comparison operators, it will become case-sensitive while `-i` will make it case-insensitive if it wasn't already. Remember to actually research first before coming to SO. A good resource is [google](https://www.google.com/)

Comment: @NekoMusume Ok.

Comment: in addition to the very obvious `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators` help topic [*grin*], there is a `flags` option for regex patterns. if you use `(?-i)` at the start of a pattern, it will toggle the `case insensitive` flag to `OFF`. lookee >>> Regular Expression Options | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options  <<<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `-cmatch`:

```
"a" -cmatch "A"
# False
```

See more information [**here**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html).